# python2.7でのデータ構造・アルゴリズムおすすめ書籍

Tags: python

現在Python(2系)を使っているのですが、データ構造・アルゴリズムの理解が乏しいた勉強したいと考えています。
調べて様々なまとめサイト、学習サイトがあるのは理解できたのですが、自分が求める形の書籍がなくもしご存知の方、
またおすすめの勉強などありましたら教えて頂けると幸いです。

現在の勉強法；
1. 基本的なデータ構造・アルゴリズムについてまとめたサイトみて理解する。
2. 競技プログラミンの練習サイトなどから、それを使った課題を見つける
3. 自分でPythonで書いてみる
4. 他の方が書いているもの見つけて、正解を考える
→探すのにいちいち時間がかかり大変なので本などにあらかたまとまってるといいな思い探したのでがpythonではいいのが見つかりませんでした。
求めるもの；
- 基本的なアルゴリズム・データ構造の内容、違い、どのように使い分けるかなど説明がある
- それを用いた課題がある
- 答えがpython(2系)で書かれている

Comment: 参考: 競技プログラミングのサイトでも、たとえば [Aizu Online Judge](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/) では他人の回答を言語別に見ることができます。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/98281

Comment: 載っていてほしいアルゴリズムやデータ構造を具体的に書いたほうが回答がつきやすいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

Web上のもので軽く探してみた限りではこれらがいいのではないでしょうか。

- [Basic Data Structures - Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/toctree.html)
- [Python-for-Algorithms--Data-Structures--and-Interviews - Github](https://github.com/jmportilla/Python-for-Algorithms--Data-Structures--and-Interviews)

python2にこだわっていらっしゃいますが、python3の方がリソースも多いのでそちらに移ることをおすすめします。